# Got a warning when creating trigger. Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors

Tags: sql, oracle

I just began to use oracle, when I create a trigger, a warning coming up. There is no error message so I can hardly debug. I think the query is correct. Anyone could help me? I'd be grateful.

```
CREATE TRIGGER "TR_SERVICE_HISTORY_MESSAGE"
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON SERVICE_HISTORY
        DECLARE FNAME(VARCHAR2 50);LNAME(VARCHAR2 50);DOGNAME(VARCHAR2 50);STOREAREA(VARCHAR2 50);DOGBREED(VARCHAR2 50);
    BEGIN
        IF(:NEW.FINISHED := 'T') THEN
        SELECT F_NAME, L_NAME, DOG_NAME, STORE_AREA DOG_BREED 
    INTO FNAME, LNAME, DOGNAME, STOREAREA, DOGBREED FROM CUSTOMERS, DOGS, STORES
        WHERE :NEW.DOG_ID = DOGS.DOG_ID, :NEW.STORE_ID = STORES.STORE_ID, CUSTOMER.C_ID = DOGS.C_ID;
        :NEW.MESSAGE :='Hi '||FNAME||' '||LNAME||', your dog '||DOGNAME|| ' of breed: '||BREEDNAME||
    ' is ready for pick-up at '||STOREAREA||'.';
    ELSE
    SELECT F_NAME, L_NAME, DOG_NAME, DOG_BREED 
    INTO FNAME, LNAME, DOGNAME, DOGBREED FROM CUSTOMERS, DOGS, STORES
        WHERE :NEW.DOG_ID = DOGS.DOG_ID, :NEW.STORE_ID = STORES.STORE_ID, CUSTOMER.C_ID = DOGS.C_ID;
    :NEW.MESSAGE :='Hi '||FNAME||' '||LNAME||', your dog '||DOGNAME|| ' of breed: '||BREEDNAME||
    ' is not ready for picked up yet.';
    END;
    /
```

Comment: [How to view compilation errors](http://razorsql.com/articles/oracle_compile_errors.html). I do notice a couple of errors in there (at least your varchar2 variable declarations), but the fact that the code is aligned at random, your lines are very long, and everything is in capitals doesn't make it very easy to debug. Also you might consider using a tool that presents these kinds of errors right away, including line numbers. I think Oracle's own [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) is free and can do this.

Comment: What tool are you using to compile your code? If it doesn't display compilation error messages then either it's useless or you're not using it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some very basic errors in your code. Here is a code block that is at least valid plsql.

```
declare
   fname     varchar2(50);
   lname     varchar2(50);
   dogname   varchar2(50);
   storearea varchar2(50);
   dogbreed  varchar2(50);
begin
   if :new.finished = 'T'
   then
      select f_name
            ,l_name
            ,dog_name
            ,store_area dog_breed
        into fname
            ,lname
            ,dogname
            ,storearea
            ,dogbreed
        from customers
            ,dogs
            ,stores
       where :new.dog_id = dogs.dog_id
         and :new.store_id = stores.store_id
         and customer.c_id = dogs.c_id;
      :new.message := 'Hi ' || fname || ' ' || lname || ', your dog ' || dogname || ' of breed: ' ||
                      breedname || ' is ready for pick-up at ' || storearea || '.';
   else
      select f_name
            ,l_name
            ,dog_name
            ,dog_breed
        into fname
            ,lname
            ,dogname
            ,dogbreed
        from customers
            ,dogs
            ,stores
       where :new.dog_id = dogs.dog_id
         and :new.store_id = stores.store_id
         and customer.c_id = dogs.c_id;

      :new.message := 'Hi ' || fname || ' ' || lname || ', your dog ' || dogname || ' of breed: ' ||
                      breedname || ' is not ready for picked up yet.';
   end if;
end;
```